# File not getting updated when using "docker cp"

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am trying to use docker cp to copy .class files from my host into the container. I am using the following command:

```
docker cp foo.class container:/path/foo.class
```

I am doing this when the server running inside the container is shutdown.

However, I am seeing that the foo.class isn't getting updated with my latest file and if I try to rm the file I get a

```
rm: cannot remove foo.class: Stale file handle
```

Here is my docker version (Docker for Mac):

```
docker version
Client:
Version:      1.13.0
API version:  1.25
Go version:   go1.7.3
Git commit:   49bf474
Built:        Wed Jan 18 16:20:26 2017
OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Wed Jan 18 16:20:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Anyone seen this happen?

TIA

Comment: How are you shutting down the container and starting the container after the copy?

Comment: I have one window that has my filesystem and the other has a docker exec into the container. The application is served by JBoss and it is shut down when transferring the files.

Comment: How are you shutting down JBoss for the file cp? How do you start the app up again after?. There's a chance you are replacing the file the in a container but not the image.

Comment: We have an application running in JBoss and we use a script to shutdown the server and then copy a bunch of class files over to the container to test some stuff. This is when the docker cp does not behave as expected. The file timestamp does not get updated and trying to rm the file generates a "Stale File Handle".